# parse.json of authenticated play request

Tags: json, scala, authentication, playframework, playframework-2.0

I've set up authentication in my application like this, always allow when a username is supplied and the API-key is 123:

```
object Auth  {
    def IsAuthenticated(block: => String => Request[AnyContent] => Result) = {
      Security.Authenticated(RetrieveUser, HandleUnauthorized) { user =>
        Action { request =>
          block(user)(request)
        }
      }
    }

    def RetrieveUser(request: RequestHeader) = {

      val auth = new String(base64Decode(request.headers.get("AUTHORIZATION").get.replaceFirst("Basic", "")))
      val split  = auth.split(":")
      val user = split(0)
      val pass = split(1)
      Option(user)
    }

    def HandleUnauthorized(request: RequestHeader) = {
      Results.Forbidden
    }

    def APIKey(apiKey: String)(f: => String => Request[AnyContent] => Result) = IsAuthenticated { user => request =>

      if(apiKey == "123")
        f(user)(request)
      else
        Results.Forbidden
    }

}
```

I want then to define a method in my controller (testOut in this case) that uses the request as application/json only. Now, before I added authentication, I'd say "def testOut = Action(parse.json) {...}", but now that I'm using authentication, how can I add parse.json in to the mix and make this work?

```
  def testOut = Auth.APIKey("123") { username => implicit request =>

    var props:Map[String, JsValue] = Map[String, JsValue]()
    request.body  match {
      case JsObject(fields) => { props = fields.toMap }
      case _ => {} // Ok("received something else: " + request.body + '\n')
    }

    if(!props.contains("UUID"))
      props.+("UUID" -> UniqueIdGenerator.uuid)

    if (!props.contains("entity"))
      props.+("entity" -> "unset")

    props.+("username" -> username)

    Ok(props.toString)
  }
```

As a bonus question, why is only UUID added to the props map, not entity and username?

Sorry about the noob factor, I'm trying to learn Scala and Play at the same time. :-)

Cheers

Nik

Comment: PS, if there are other things in here that I'm obviously doing wrong, do feel free to point them out, so I can go in the right direction instead :-)

Comment: You can use `map(key) = value` instead of `map.+(key -> value)` and `map.getOrElseUpdate(key, value)` instead of `if (!map.contains(key) map(key) = value)`.

Comment: You can use `case _ =>` instead of `case _ => {}`. And you don't need curly braces here: `case JsObject(fields) => { props = fields.toMap }`.

Comment: You are using immutable map (since `toMap` returns immutable map), so you can't update it. And method `+` of `Map` creates a new Map, without updating current. You can use `map += key -> value` to replace map with new version.

Comment: Thank you very much for the map-input, @senia. :-) Any suggestion of where to add parse.json to get a Request[JsValue] instead of Request[AnyContent]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I don't need to use a bodyparser at all, request.body has a asJson function that I can use. So I exploited this to do the following. This work, and I can continue my work, but I still don't quite understand how to get a JSON body parser in here. Learning in progress… ;-)

```
def testOut = Auth.APIKey("123") { username => request =>

  var props:Map[String, JsValue] = Map[String, JsValue]()
  request.body.asJson  match {
    case None => {}
    case Some(x) => {
      x match {
        case JsObject(fields) => { props = fields.toMap }
        case _ => {} // Ok("received something else: " + request.body + '\n')
      }
    }
  }

  if(!props.contains("UUID"))
    props += "UUID" -> toJson(UniqueIdGenerator.uuid)

  if(!props.contains("entity"))
    props += "entity" -> toJson("unset")

  props += "should" -> toJson("appear")
  props += "username" -> toJson(username)

  Ok(props.toString)
}
```

Comment: Again, please also leave comments about anything that should be done differently :-)

Comment: Some improvements in `Option` usage: `var props = request.body.asJson.collect{ case JsObject(fields) => fields.toMap}.getOrElse(Map())`

Comment: I would not use mutable objects as [this tutorial](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-idiom-immutable-code-functional-programming-immutability) quotes: **_Using vals in your code makes you think about alternative, immutable, functional code. This small example demonstrates that removing vars leads to refactoring. The refactoring leads to new coding patterns. New coding patterns leads to a shift in your approach to programming. This shift in approach leads to transformative code that has fewer defects and is easier to maintain._**. It takes a little getting used to but is the way to go!

Answer (score 1):

See my answer to this question here: [Play 2.0 Framework, using a BodyParser with an authenticated request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11104005/play-2-0-framework-using-a-bodyparser-with-an-authenticated-request)

The gist is that I overloaded the IsAuthenticated method to take `BodyParser` as a parameter and call `Action` with it.