# Play 2.0 Framework, using a BodyParser with an authenticated request

Tags: parsing, scala, playframework

I'd like to be able to use a BodyParser on an authenticated request and I'm having trouble figuring out how to do that if my Authentication is set up like the ZenTasks example.

My authentication method,

```
def IsAuthenticated(f: => String => Request[AnyContent] => Result) = {
  Security.Authenticated(username, onUnauthorized) { user =>
    Action(request => f(user)(request))
  }
}

def HasRole(role: List[String])
  (f: => String => Request[AnyContent] => Result) = IsAuthenticated {
  user => request => if (role.contains(getRole(user))) {
    f(user)(request) // This function returns the result.
  } else {
    Results.Forbidden
  }
}
```

My controller method,

```
def controller = HasRole(List("admin")) { user => _ => { 
  Action(parse.temporaryFile){ implicit request =>
    request.body.moveTo(new File("/tmp/filepath"))
    Redirect(routes.home)
  }
}
```

This is the error I'm seeing,

```
[error]  found   : play.api.mvc.Action[play.api.libs.Files.TemporaryFile]
[error]  required: play.api.mvc.Result
[error]       Action(parse.temporaryFile){ implicit request =>
[error]                                  ^
```

Here is a related question: [parse.json of authenticated play request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10054619/parse-json-of-authenticated-play-request)

This person found a workaround, and I believe there is one for the temporary file example as well, but I'd like to know how (or why) what I'm doing is not working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe I've figured this out, mainly because I left some details out of the original question that I did not realize were important.

The problem was that I was wrapping an `Action { Action { } }` because the `IsAuthenticated` method already had a call to the `Action` function inside it.  What I ended up doing was overloading the `IsAuthenticated` function with a method that took `BodyParser` as a parameter.  Because I am using the `TemporaryFile` method, which is not a subclass of `AnyContent`, I also had to change the request type.

Now, this is what my `Secured` trait looks like:

```
def IsAuthenticated(f: => String => Request[Any] => Result) = {
  Security.Authenticated(username, onUnauthorized) { user =>
    Action(request => f(user)(request))
  }
}

def IsAuthenticated(b: BodyParser[Any] = parse.anyContent)
  (f: => String => Request[Any] => Result) = {
  Security.Authenticated(username, onUnauthorized) { user =>
    Action(b)(request => f(user)(request))
  }
}

def HasRole(role: List[String])(b: BodyParser[Any] = parse.anyContent)
  (f: => String => Request[Any] => Result) = IsAuthenticated(b) {
  user => request => getRole(user) match {
    case Some(r) if role.contains(r) => f(user)(request)
    case _ => Results.Forbidden
  }
}
```

And this is what my controller looks like:

```
def controller = HasRole(List("admin"))(parse.temporaryFile) { user => request =>
  request.body match {
    case b:TemporaryFile => b.moveTo(new File("/tmp/file"))
    case _ => Status(404)
  }
}
```

Hope this helps someone else!